# How Can I Override Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, response.redirect

Hi I have 2 different project. While moving from one to the other I am using Response.Redirect but I want to change url inside of the response.redirect in all project so I dont want to use directly response.redirect. I want to override response.redirect. When new developers comes to our team they still should use response.redirect but after this, method can be redirect my method which has same name.

For example

I have this codes

```
Response.Redirect("/Personel/Information.aspx")
```

Then I want override this method

```
public static class Response
{
    public static void Redirect(string url)
    {
        if (url.Contains("Personnel"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Customer/" + url);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. You *might* be able to achieve this using a custom `IHttpModule` implementation; in the `EndRequest` event, check `IsRequestBeingRedirected` and update the `RedirectLocation` property accordingly.

Comment: Use an extension method for the Response class.